# Installing Raspbian from NOOBS without a keyboard, mouse and display

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero-w, noobs, headless

I have a RPI 0 W, a 8GB Micro sd card with NOOBS on it. 
I want to install the Raspbian on RPI 0 W. Is it possible to do so with the help of my laptop? If yes, how should I proceed? If not, what else can I do right now?

Comment: Why NOOBS? Are you trying to get dual-boot working? If not go with plain Raspbian - it's easier to get running on a headless system.

Comment: Oh thanks. How would I install it, like, no keyboard, mouse, monitor for it. Only my laptop and the pi.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use plain Raspbian downloaded from [Full Raspbian with everything](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_full_latest) or from [Raspbian with desktop](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_latest) or [Raspbian Lite](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_lite_latest).

Write that to your SDCard with [Balena Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/).

Before booting the card, eject it from your laptop and re-insert it (ignore any Windows requests to reformat the SDCard or you'll have to start over) create two files `F:\ssh.txt` (which can have any content you like) and `F:\wpa_supplicant.conf` with

```
country=GB
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
network={
    ssid="YourWiFiSSID"
    psk="yourSecretWiFipassword"
}
```

Remembering to change `country=GB` to your 2-char ISO country code if you're not in the "Un-tied Kingdom of No Sane Government".